# Criar tuplas com valores aleatórios

Tags: python, python-3.x, tupla

É possível criar uma tupla com tamanho e valores aleatórios? Se sim, como?

ex: Run -->(0, 4 , 5)
    Run --> (2, 1, 7, 9)
    Run --> (7)...
Se fosse uma lista eu usaria o código:

```
from random import randint

list = [randint(i + 1, 9) for i in range(randint(1, 5))]

print(lis)
```

Mas ao transformar a variavel em tupla com o mesmo código:

```
from random import randint

tup = (randint(i + 1, 9) for i in range(randint(1, 5)))

print(tup)
```

Recebo unicamente a mensagem:
generator object genexpr at 0x00000186F02FEB10>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando a forma literal de uma tupla, precisa usar a função de criação de uma, aí pode usar o `for` normalmente:

```
from random import randint

tupla = tuple(randint(i + 1, 9) for i in range(randint(1, 5)))
print(tupla)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JdDLwh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/TupleFromComprehension). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/TupleFromComprehension.py).

Comment: Uma função que é apenas uma pequena menção na documentação do python,  alguma dica onde poderia achar mais informações?

Comment: Não sei de nada confiável além da documentação, mas ela não tem segredo.

Answer (score -1):

Fiz essa solução com o sample da biblioteca random:

`from random import sample

num = tuple(sample(range(10), 5))

print(f'Os números gerados foram {sorted(num)}')`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).